# Html helper LabelFor doesn't render title (tooltip)

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, label, title

On my view i use html helper `LabelFor`. Label Text sometimes is too long, so i set `max-width` for label. Now it looks like this :

`Label for some fi...` while the full text is `Label for some field`

So in this case will be greate to show title of label to see the full text.

But standart html helper doesn't add title to html.

How can i resolve my problem using html helpers?

---

### Example what i need without Html Helpers : http://jsfiddle.net/fdf5kx5z/4/

Comment: Do you mean you want to have the full text in a tooltip?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, yes. I can do it manualy like this http://jsfiddle.net/fdf5kx5z/4/ but it will take to much time as i have already view with helpers

Comment: You can add html attributes with `LabelFor()` but if your doing this regularly, it might be worth creating your own html helper that adds it automatically.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, yes i also thinking about it. So, ok, will create own helper. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom html helper for this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace YourAssembly.Html
{
  public static class LabelHelpers
  {
    public static MvcHtmlString TooltipLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
      ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
      Dictionary<string, object> attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
      attributes.Add("title", metaData.GetDisplayName());
      return helper.LabelFor(expression, attributes);
    }
  }
}
```

and add a reference  to the `<namespaces>` section of `web.config`

```
<add namespace="YourAssembly.Html "/>
```

Comment: You might also want to consider adding `attributes.Add("class", "YourClassName");` as well so you can easily style the label with css (width, text-ellipses etc)